# Compile error when using vl_compilenn in Mathconvnet in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, matlab, mex, vlfeat

I am trying to use Mathconvnet library/package of Matlab for using CNN. While trying to compile the package using the function
    [`vl_compilenn`](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_compilenn/) following this guide http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/#compiling  i'm facing errors.

**Steps Already Taken:**

1. Installed/uninstalled then reinstalled Microsoft SDK latest version.
2. Added path in Environment variable
3. Used Command mex -setup c++ to change compiler to C++

Here is [the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRVrp.png) I am getting.

After various stack overflow answers that i went through i have also done this

1.) `vl_compilenn('EnableImreadJpeg ',false)` although I get different error when I do this.

2.) added `gdiplus.lib` in matlab sys subfolder

EDIT: Solution is to choose a Visual Studio Compiler 12 or above, if already installed type 
        `mex -setup -v`in Matlab which will show available compilers for choosing,select the latest one available.
if still getting the same error choose same compiler for both `mex-setup c++` and `mex-setup c` and type the command again: 
`vl_compilenn('EnableImreadJpeg',false)`.

Comment: Does support Mingw your matlab version? If it is supported, try to disable antivirus program.

Comment: mingw C,c++ are supported in my matlab version but i guess they aren't supported for Mathconvnet for that one will need Microsoft SDK 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to choose a Visual Studio Compiler 12 or above, if already installed type 
        `mex -setup -v`in Matlab which will show available compilers for choosing,select the latest one available.
if still getting the same error choose same compiler for both `mex-setup c++` and `mex-setup c` and type the command again: 
`vl_compilenn('EnableImreadJpeg',false)`.